# Проблема с указателями

Tags: c, указатели

Почему, когда я добавляю закомментированный код, у меня происходит крах?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char string[100];
int i = 0;

void read(char *p){
    p = &string[i];
    while((string[i] = getchar()) != '\n')
    i++;
    string[i++] = '\0';

}

int main(){
    char *line[10];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        read(line[i]);

   /* for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      printf("%s\n", line[i]); */

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: потому что line[i] не инициализированны. как минимум присваивай их по возвращаемому значению, или передавай указатель на указатель в `read()`. А вообще хорошо бы аллоцировать под них память в куче... и ещё 5—10 проблем в коде, для которых комментария не хватит.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`line` в контексте данного кода — это массив из 10 строк, то есть указателей на символы (символами я называю тип `char`); для уменьшения путаницы я буду называть эти указатели значениями. Как я понял ваш код, вы хотите в функции `read` изменить это самое значение в массиве `line`. Однако ваш код меняет только значение переменной `p` внутри функции, а сам массив `line` в результате остаётся неинициализированным. Чтобы изменить значение в самом массиве `line`, вам нужно передать указатель на значение (то есть указатель на указатель) и в функции менять значение по указателю. Приведённый ниже код работает:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char string[100];
int i = 0;

void read(char **p){
    /* Меняем значение не в переменной внутри функции, */
    /* а в том месте, куда указывает указатель */
    *p = &string[i];

    while((string[i] = getchar()) != '\n')
    i++;
    string[i++] = '\0';

}

int main(){
    char *line[3];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        read(&line[i]);  /* Передаём указатель на значение массива */

   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
      printf("%s\n", line[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Помимо указанной, в коде есть другие проблемы: например, ваш `string` вмещает всего сто символов, соответственно попытка прочитать более ста символов может привести к неопределённому поведению, в частности к краху. А ещё у вас блоки кода оформлены плохо, что может запутать читателя. Но это не по теме вопроса, и, надеюсь, вы это всё сами понимаете :)